# In tensorflow, is there a way for generating a new tensor from a given tensor in the given manner?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensor

In the code below:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import keras.backend as kb

ip1 = keras.Input((20,), name='ip1')
ip2 = keras.Input((20,), name='ip2')
ip3 = keras.Input((20,), name='ip3')
ip4 = keras.Input((20,), name='ip4')
ip5 = keras.Input((20,), name='ip5')
ip6 = keras.Input((20,), name='ip6')
ip7 = keras.Input((20,), name='ip7')
ip8 = keras.Input((20,), name='ip8')
ip9 = keras.Input((20,), name='ip9')

ip_concat = kb.stack([ip1, ip2, ip3, ip4, ip5, ip6, ip7, ip8, ip9], axis=1)

rel_features = layers.Dense(128, input_shape=(9, 20))(ip_concat)

f1_enc = layers.Dense(64, activation='tanh', input_shape=(9, 128))(rel_features)
```

Here, the `f1_enc` has a shape of 9x64. Now, what I need to do can be understood from the example given below. For the sake of simplicity, instead of a 9x64 tensor, I have kept the initial tensor  to be 3x3:

```
[[a, b, c],
 [d, e, f],
 [g, h, i]]
```

needs to be converted to a 3x3x6 tensor as follows:

```
[[[a, b, c, a, b, c],
  [a, b, c, d, e, f],
  [a, b, c, g, h, i]],

[[d, e, f, a, b, c],
 [d, e, f, d, e, f],
 [d, e, f, g, h, i]],

[[g, h, i, a, b, c],
 [g, h, i, d, e, f],
 [g, h, i, g, h, i]]]
```

I know that the tensors are immutable in tensorflow, so looping over the tensor and reassigning the values to a new tensor won't work.

Also, I tried fiddling with eager execution because the conversion of the tensor to a numpy matrix did not work. From what I understand now, the strategy to convert the tensor to numpy matrix does not work because we are working with keras layer.

While the code will need to be backpropagated to the `ip_concat`, it will **not** need to backpropagate through the new tensor. There is going to be a connection from `ip_concat` to another keras layer later.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the most efficient way but:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

tensor = tf.constant([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])
print(tensor)
# tf.Tensor(
# [[1 2 3]
#  [4 5 6]
#  [7 8 9]], shape=(3, 3), dtype=int32)

x = tensor.numpy()
tensor = tf.constant([[np.concatenate((j, i)) for i in x] for j in x])
print(tensor)
# tf.Tensor(
# [[[1 2 3 1 2 3]
#   [1 2 3 4 5 6]
#   [1 2 3 7 8 9]]
#  [[4 5 6 1 2 3]
#   [4 5 6 4 5 6]
#   [4 5 6 7 8 9]]
#  [[7 8 9 1 2 3]
#   [7 8 9 4 5 6]
#   [7 8 9 7 8 9]]], shape=(3, 3, 6), dtype=int32)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a combination of `tf.unstack`, `tf.tile`, `tf.reshape` and `tf.concat`. Our initial tensor `A`:

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 3), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]], dtype=int32)>
```

First, unstack the rows:

```
A1, A2, A3 = tf.unstack(A, axis=0)
```

Output:

```
(<tf.Tensor: shape=(3,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([1, 2, 3], dtype=int32)>,
 <tf.Tensor: shape=(3,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([4, 5, 6], dtype=int32)>,
 <tf.Tensor: shape=(3,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([7, 8, 9], dtype=int32)>)
```

Then `tile` and `reshape`:

```
L1, L2, L3 = [tf.reshape(tf.tile(X, [3]), (3,3)) for X in [A1, A2, A3]]
```

Output:

```
(<tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 3), dtype=int32, numpy=
 array([[1, 2, 3],
        [1, 2, 3],
        [1, 2, 3]], dtype=int32)>,
 <tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 3), dtype=int32, numpy=
 array([[4, 5, 6],
        [4, 5, 6],
        [4, 5, 6]], dtype=int32)>,
 <tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 3), dtype=int32, numpy=
 array([[7, 8, 9],
        [7, 8, 9],
        [7, 8, 9]], dtype=int32)>)
```

Then concatenate with the initial tensor:

```
R1, R2, R3 = [tf.concat([X, A], axis=1) for X in [L1, L2, L3]]
```

Output:

```
(<tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 6), dtype=int32, numpy=
 array([[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3],
        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
        [1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9]], dtype=int32)>,
 <tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 6), dtype=int32, numpy=
 array([[4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 6],
        [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]], dtype=int32)>,
 <tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 6), dtype=int32, numpy=
 array([[7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3],
        [7, 8, 9, 4, 5, 6],
        [7, 8, 9, 7, 8, 9]], dtype=int32)>)
```